# Posting a php foreach loop in database,data is inserting wrong

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a cart where all my products are generated inside of a foreach loop that stores them in sessions.
And i want to post  each product in my Table:orders.
But i am getting some errors.

*Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\clientes\gallery\postOrder.php on line 46*

*Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\clientes\gallery\postOrder.php on line 54*

what i am trying to post...

```
Array
(
    [numero] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [vari] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

    [desenho] => Array
        (
            [0] => img/1.0.png
            [1] => img/1-1.png
            [2] => img/1-2.png
            [3] => img/1-3.png
        )

    [fabric] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 45
            [3] => 50
        )

    [qnty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    //some other arrays 

    [submit_post] => Enviar
)
```

This is my [foreach loop code](http://pastebin.com/BHDVkUUP)

I am trying to post this way...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_post'])){
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $size = isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : array();
        $numero = isset($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : array();
        $vari = isset($_POST['vari']) ? $_POST['vari'] : array();
        $desenho = isset($_POST['desenho']) ? $_POST['desenho'] : array();
        $fabric = isset($_POST['fabric']) ? $_POST['fabric'] : array();
        $size = isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : array();
        $qnty = isset($_POST['qnty']) ? $_POST['qnty'] : array();
        $cost = isset($_POST['cost']) ? $_POST['cost']: array();
        $subtotal = isset($_POST['subtotal']) ? $_POST['subtotal'] : array();
        $total = isset($_POST['total']) ? $_POST['total'] : array();
        $all_products = isset($_POST['all_products']) ? $_POST['all_products'] : array();
        $subT=0;

        $pedido=$date." ".$_SESSION['userName']."-".$_SESSION['userLName'];
//46    $query = "SELECT * FROM almofadas WHERE id_price='$fabric'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
         while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $tecido=$rows['tecido'];

        }

        $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO orders (fabric,size,product_quantity,order_id,product_img,product_title,variante,product_cost,product_subtotal) 
//54                    VALUES ('$fabric', '$size' , '$qnty', '$pedido', '$desenho', '$numero', '$vari', '$cost', '$subT')";
        if ($conn->query($ins_sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
            echo "Error: " ;
            }
        $conn->close();
                     }
```

What i am doing wrong,how i will fix this?

Comment: to insert bulk records you need to create value set like 

INSERT INTO orders ("field1","field2","fieldN") values("value1","value2","valueN"), ("value1","value2","valueN"),("value1","value2","valueN"),("value1","value2","valueN"),("value1","value2","valueN");

Comment: This error message is pretty clear - you're converting an array into a string. In this case, `$fabric` in line 46 is an array. You don't want to do that.

Comment: convert your array value set into data value set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to insert array instead of single item as value.

Put all your insertion code inside a `foreach` loop

```
foreach($fabrics as $fabric)
{
    $pedido=$date." ".$_SESSION['userName']."-".$_SESSION['userLName'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM almofadas WHERE id_price='$fabric'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
     while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $tecido=$rows['tecido'];

    }

    // search for index of current item
    $index = array_search($f, $fabric);

    // write your insert code here where column values should be like $fabric[$index], $size[$index] and so on. 
    // I mean you need to fetch array element by index.
}
```

Comment: Look how i did [mycode](https://codeshare.io/PYa6t) but i'm getting a new error,btw this code can be edited in the link.

Comment: this is the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: Sorry for this silly mistake. It should be `$fabric[$index]`, not `$fabric['index']`. Also I am working with your code. Foreach misplaced there.

Comment: i am using a session for it `$subtotal=$value * $_SESSION['icms'.$id];`

Comment: but for testing propose it can work `subtotal = quantity * price`

Answer (score 0):

Fix your variables because their default values are array:

```
  $fabric = isset($_POST['fabric']) ? $_POST['fabric'] : array();
```

Do:

```
  $fabric = isset($_POST['fabric']) ? $_POST['fabric'] : '';
```

Instead. And do SELECT query only when $fabric is set.

Comment: How did you do it?